# argparse - optional argument without prefix

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Related:

[Using argparse for mandatory argument without prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642397/using-argparse-for-mandatory-argument-without-prefix)

[Python: argparse optional arguments without dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310626/python-argparse-optional-arguments-without-dashes)

I need a simple script that accepts either `./x start` or `./x stop`. And `start` and `stop` should have their own entries in the help menu.

This doesn't seem super-doable with argparse.

I get close with

```
parser.add_argument('--start', action='store_true', help='stuff')
parser.add_argument('--stop', action='store_true', help='stuff2')
```

but, this requires preceding dashes before each argument.

Is there a way to do this without sub-commands? (Especially since both`start` and `stop` accept the same set of optional flags).

Comment: `add_argument('foobar', choices=['start', 'stop'], help='a positional that accepts one of two words')`

Comment: @hpaulj: why won't you add it as an answer to get accepted by @Roymunson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parser.add_argument('foobar', choices=['start', 'stop'], 
    help='a positional that accepts one of two words')
```